# Webscraping - Clicking on Advanced Search Tab will not maximize the tab

Tags: python, selenium, click

I am navigating this website https://portal.betterwork.org/transparency/compliance and I am trying to type the name of a specific factory inside the Advanced Search 'Factory' box.

I noticed that if I do not manually click on the box while the browser is controlled by Selenium, I won't be able to type any factory name and the system stops (or crashes).

This is what I have so far

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://portal.betterwork.org/transparency/compliance#")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

element = driver.find_element_by_id("pnlHdAdvanceSearch")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
element = driver.find_element_by_id("txtSearchFactory")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
element.send_keys('PT Glory Industrial Semarang Demak')
element = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearchData")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elemnts = find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
print(elemnts)
```

What exactly is the problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need proper synchronization to perform the action you need

1. Once navigate to your URL, It started showing 2 loaders so you need to wait until both of them gets hidden
2. expand the advanced search > enter text and hit search button

Use below code. I checked at my end and its working flawlessly.

```
driver.get('https://portal.betterwork.org/transparency/compliance')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 45)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.ID, "loader-wrapper")))
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.k-loading-mask")))
input_text = 'Namlee International Co. Ltd.'
driver.find_element_by_id("pnlHdAdvanceSearch").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("txtSearchFactory").send_keys(input_text)
driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearchData").click()
view_button = "//tr[contains(.,'{}')]/td/a"
time.sleep(3)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, view_button.format(input_text)))).click()
```

Comment: This is great thanks! What was the problem? Now, I  manage to actually get the results for the factory, but I am trying to also click on the view botton to get the details of the factory. However, driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='grdSuppliers']/table/tbody/tr/td[10]/a").click() does not seem to work? It says the element is not interactable?

Comment: There are 30 view button elements are there on page which matches with `//*[@id='grdSuppliers']/table/tbody/tr/td[10]/a`. Which one do you need to click ?

Comment: Say that I search for "Namlee International Co. Ltd.", I retrieve the result for one factory. That factory has one 'View' button under the additional information column, I am failing to click on it and scrape the text in the results, it would be great if you could help me!

Comment: Then use below xpath `//tr[contains(.,'Namlee International Co. Ltd.')]/td/a`

Comment: I am sorry, I am not being clear. I manage to write Namlee International Co. Ltd. in the factory text bottom, click on search  and get the results. Now, In the result box there is the 'Additional Information' column. How do I click on the 'View' button in that column?

Comment: Updated my answer. hope this will help you

Comment: Yes it works, I just need you to help me get the text of the View box result :) Please!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215732/discussion-between-filippo-sebastio-and-narendrar).